# Interacting with avatar using Kinect and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I want to move the avatar based on the movement the player using kinect and Unity, are there any good tutorials?

We are using unity and Kinect interface to create a simple application. Based on the movement of the player we need to move the avatar.

We are supposed to use `Unity` with `GAKUNITY`, No OpenNI or any third party tools.

Are there any good tutorials for `GakUnity with Kinect`?

`GAK` means `Gadget Accelerator Kit`

We just want to move any `avatar` with player movement in front of kinect interface. Even help in hand movement also highly appreciated.

You can also share useful links or books regarding to unity and kinect programming.

Comment: If you're looking to do Kinect programming you basically have two paths.  One is using [Microsoft's Official SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/overview.aspx) which limits you to Windows and currently is not supposed to be used for commercial purposes.  Your other option, which I would recommend is [OpenNI](http://75.98.78.94/default.aspx).  Both provide skeletal tracking, but you're ultimately responsible for tying it into your 3D engine.

Comment: @vpiTriumph do you know anything about `GAKUNITY`

Comment: any progres on your problem ?

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda Lol, i search `GAKUNITY` in google and the first result is this question

Comment: @OutlawLemur `GAKUNITY` means `gadget accelerator kit` for `unity 3d`

Comment: @RaghuveerGuthikonda Why do you have to use `GAKUNITY`? Why can't you just use the `SDK` or `OpenNI`?

Comment: @OutlawLemur we are restricted to Unity only no third party tools even opensource also not allowed

Comment: @RVG Where is the download for GAKUNITY?

Comment: @Kinected It's not publicly downloadable you have to register for imagine cup to download this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ### [Custom Kinect Gesture Recognition using OpenNI and Unity3D](http://kinect.dashhacks.com/kinect-guides/2011/06/24/custom-kinect-gesture-recognition-using-openni-and-unity3d)
> <sup>kinect.dashhacks.com</sup>
>
> A tipster has tipped a lil tipple my way in the form of custom gesture recognition for the Kinect using OpenNI and Unity 3D. What this allows you to do is create you own custom gesture that are recognized by the kinect through the software interface.

> ### [Unity and Kinect tutorial](http://www.nightmarekitty.com/2011/10/28/unity-and-kinect-tutorial/)
> <sup>nightmarekitty.com</sup>
>
> For this chapter, we are going to be using a very popular game engine called Unity. By integrating OpenNI, Nite and Sensor Kinect into Unity we will control a 3d character and multiple user interfaces. After we cover the main Components, we will build an example of each from the bottom up.

> ### [Kinect Wrapper Example Project](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/images/f/f4/NewKinect.zip)
> <sup>wiki.etc.cmu.edu</sup>
>
> This scene shows you how a skeleton is generated / tracked by placing spheres at each of the bones tracked by the Kinect, and how to use kinect to control your model. Use this to get a feel for what the Kinect is capable of. It also shows you how to prepare your GameObjects

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Unity 3d,but you can try using kinect with XNA. At the latest version of Kinect for windows SDK 1.5 and Developer Tookit 1.5.1,there is a sample demonstrating how to interact with 3d avatar using Kinect and XNA,you can find more information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131041

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about GAKUNity, but you can use zigfu plugin for unity3d and do your project. It has got sample codes and character which you can use for reference, and the sample codes are commented nicely .

You can just import your bone, drag your bones on the zigskeleton script . just read through th zig skeleton script and you will understand the function and structures they are using.

And you can even refer the MEET THE KINECT book, they have explained about using zigfu in unity .